# Expo SDK38 upgrade - fontFamily "FontAwesome" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync

Tags: react-native, expo

Since I have upgraded to Expo SDK 38, I am getting this error when I start my app.  I need to upgrade to SDK38 because Android will not let me publish at any less version.

This was working fine on SDK37, the only thing that I have changed is that I have upgraded all packages using expo upgrade, also there was an error `error: unknown option --assetExts` so I had to remove this from the app.json, which may be the cause. I changed `assetExts` to `sourceExts` which made it compile but maybe this is stopping the fonts working..

```
"packagerOpts": {         
    "assetExts": ["otf", "ttf"]    
},
```

[image]

I am following the example here of preloading the font in my App.js which is what all other answers that I can find are suggesting to do, but still getting the error.

I have also tried deleting my node_modules, package.json.lock and .expo folders, all which have not helped.

https://docs.expo.io/guides/preloading-and-caching-assets/#pre-loading-and-caching-assets

```
import { FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";

function cacheFonts(fonts) {
    return fonts.map((font) => Font.loadAsync(font));
}

const fontAssets = cacheFonts([FontAwesome.font]);
await Promise.all([...fontAssets]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was a cache issue, the code was absolutely fine.  I thought I had cleared everything but obviously not.

Deleted node_modules, package.json.lock again and npm installed and worked fine.

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me.